# Objective-C – Comparing an int to an object stored in an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am currently going through some of the questions on project Euler and I am stuck on 7, for the way I want to solve it I need want to compare a value in an array of primes (which I store as an `NSMutableArray`) to a number (which I store as an `int`) using

```
if (num%[Primes objectAtIndex:currentPrime]==0){
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the modulo (or any other) operator on an object, such as an `NSNumber` which is presumably in your array. Use the `intValue` method to convert the number in the array to the primitive `int` type:

```
if (num % [[primes objectAtIndex:currentPrime] intValue] == 0) {
```

Variable names should be lowercase in Objective-C, uppercase names are conventionally reserved for class names.

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck with that! Back to the questions.